# mercurial (hg): replace subdirectory with subrepository

Tags: mercurial

Let there is a hg repository with the following layout:

`./...
./sub
./sub/...`

At the specific moment of time, one need to drop subdirectory sub, and put a subrepo with the same name on its place. How to do this correctly?
Straightforward approach makes the history unaccessible with the following error at `hg up -r`:

`abort: path 'sub/sub' is inside nested repo 'sub'`

Answer (score 0):

- "make the history unaccessible" is sadly bad and wrong idea
- Read about proper creating and using of [Subrepositories](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#converting-folder-into-a-subrepository)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that in the example "Converting Folder Into a Subrepository" the history is not preserved? I've just had a new repository tree split out the old one.

Comment: @0x2207 - no, history **is preserved** (see my p.1) If you still want remove history - you have to use different pattern: write another filemap for converting repo into new *without subfolder* and `hg init` in subfolder

Comment: There is misunderstanding. I do want preserve history.